# using external schemas in RAML

Tags: json, schema, raml

I have a RAML specification where i would like to reference JSON schemas in other projects in different folders.

How do I do that?

I could only find that you can reference a schema via a url like so:

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title":"error",
    "description":"schema for api specified errors",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":
{
```

**Potential solution**:

```
title: BirthdayParty
baseUri: http://bouncyouse.com/{version}
schemas:
 - DaddySchema !include C:/projects/schema/Daddy1
 - MommySchema !include C:/projects/schema/Mommy2
```

Comment: Are you asking about referencing JSON Schemas from a RAML spec or including RAML fragments in a RAML spec?

Comment: Assumed you want to reference JSON schemas not RAML specs and reworded your question accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

In your RAML you can include different JSON schemas from the same or different folders.
For example:

```
title: GitHub API
version: v3
baseUri: https://api.github.com
mediaType:  application/json
schemas:
  - User:  schema/user.json
  - Users: schema/users.json
  - Org:   schema/org.json
  - Orgs:  schema/orgs.json
/root:
   post:
      body:
          schema: User
```

For referencing inside a JSON schema you can use **id** and **$ref**:

- http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor25
- http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html

Comment: can you show can example for including a JSON schema from `C:\Documents\MyProject\DaddySchema`?

Comment: Have you tried `file://C/Documents/MyProject/DaddySchema` ? BTW this is a very bad idea. This will prevent others to work on your project as the schema are not checked in with the RAML spec. Plus this exposes your project to uncontrolled changes on these external files. This will come and bite you.

Comment: I think it's a triple slash actually: `file:///C/`, not sure, not using Windows.

Comment: @bouncingHippo What tool you are using ? 
I agree with David that a relative path would be better